# Parse GML file to java object

Tags: java, gml

Is there a way to parse an GML file to Java Obeject like Jaxb do with xml file ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
    <version>??</version>
</dependency>
```

My GML file has this form:

```
        graph [

      directed 0

      node [
        id 1
        label "{C28}    {V46, V82}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 2
        label "{C8}    {V28, V46}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 3
        label "{C20}    {V46, V50}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 4
        label "{C10}    {V46, V31}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 5
        label "{C22}    {V46, V56}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 6
        label "{C24}    {V46, V69}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 7
        label "{C26}    {V46, V70}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 8
        label "{C83}    {V46, V0, V24, V13, V71}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 9
        label "{C46}    {V46, V0, V83}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 10
        label "{C45}    {V46, V0, V53}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 11
        label "{C8, C146}    {V46, V0, V24, V95, V57, V13, V68, V99, V89, V92, V35}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 12
        label "{C52}    {V24, V95, V45}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 13
        label "{C68}    {V0, V24, V95, V40}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 14
        label "{C70}    {V0, V24, V95, V94}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 15
        label "{C57}    {V32, V33, V94}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 16
        label "{C82}    {V0, V24, V95, V13, V21}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 17
        label "{C84}    {V0, V24, V95, V13, V74}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 18
        label "{C113}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V65}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 19
        label "{C96}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V22}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 20
        label "{C95}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V20}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 21
        label "{C107}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V48}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 22
        label "{C104}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V42}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 23
        label "{C117}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V73}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 24
        label "{C88}    {V0, V13, V99, V5, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 25
        label "{C106}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V47}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 26
        label "{C125}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V93}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 27
        label "{C119}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V77}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 28
        label "{C90}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V10}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 29
        label "{C112}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V63}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 30
        label "{C111}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V62}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 31
        label "{C40, C121}    {V80, V85, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 32
        label "{C109}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V59}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 33
        label "{C114}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V66}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 34
        label "{C124}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V86}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 35
        label "{C115}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V67}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 36
        label "{C103}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V37}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 37
        label "{C102}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V30}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 38
        label "{C122}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V84}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 39
        label "{C116}    {V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V72}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 40
        label "{C138}    {V0, V57, V13, V99, V89, V92, V49}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 41
        label "{C128}    {V46, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92, V16}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 42
        label "{C126}    {V0, V24, V13, V99, V89, V92, V7}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 43
        label "{C63, C129}    {V46, V0, V13, V17, V58, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 44
        label "{C65, C135}    {V46, V0, V13, V58, V98, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 45
        label "{C139}    {V0, V57, V13, V99, V89, V92, V61}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 46
        label "{C132}    {V0, V24, V13, V99, V89, V92, V55}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 47
        label "{C30, C134}    {V46, V51, V75, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 48
        label "{C48, C146}    {V0, V24, V95, V60, V91, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 49
        label "{C47, C48}    {V1, V24, V95, V60, V91}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 50
        label "{C131}    {V0, V24, V13, V99, V89, V92, V54}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 51
        label "{C142}    {V0, V24, V57, V13, V99, V89, V92, V27}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 52
        label "{C130, C146}    {V46, V81, V0, V24, V95, V13, V68, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 53
        label "{C16, C98}    {V46, V81, V88, V0, V24, V95, V13}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 54
        label "{C69, C98}    {V81, V64, V88, V0, V24, V95, V13}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 55
        label "{C32, C85}    {V64, V87, V0, V24, V95, V13}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 56
        label "{C36, C71, C101, C130}    {V46, V81, V76, V0, V24, V95, V29, V13, V2, V11, V18, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 57
        label "{C145}    {V81, V0, V24, V95, V2, V3, V96, V97, V100}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 58
        label "{C36, C118}    {V76, V78, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 59
        label "{C56, C71, C74, C130}    {V46, V81, V76, V79, V0, V24, V95, V29, V2, V11, V18}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 60
        label "{C44, C56, C71, C74}    {V46, V76, V79, V0, V29, V102, V2, V11, V18}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 61
        label "{C44, C56, C58, C74}    {V46, V34, V76, V79, V0, V38, V29, V102, V107}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 62
        label "{C56, C75}    {V38, V29, V109, V102, V107}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 63
        label "{C56, C77}    {V109, V102, V105, V104, V107}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 64
        label "{C78}    {V109, V105, V106, V108}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 65
        label "{C58, C60}    {V109, V101, V102, V105, V107}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 66
        label "{C58, C75}    {V101, V102, V105, V107, V103}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 67
        label "{C76}    {V102, V105, V103, V110}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 68
        label "{C72, C146}    {V81, V0, V24, V95, V6, V13, V68, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 69
        label "{C62, C127}    {V8, V9, V0, V24, V6, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 70
        label "{C16, C143}    {V46, V36, V81, V0, V24, V95, V13, V68, V99}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 71
        label "{C14, C130}    {V46, V36, V41, V81, V0, V24, V95, V13}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 72
        label "{C14, C86}    {V46, V41, V24, V95, V4, V13}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 73
        label "{C47, C49}    {V24, V95, V4, V90}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 74
        label "{C47, C66, C140}    {V12, V46, V0, V24, V57, V13, V43, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 75
        label "{C2, C92}    {V12, V14, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 76
        label "{C66, C141}    {V0, V24, V57, V13, V15, V43, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 77
        label "{C66, C105}    {V0, V44, V13, V15, V43, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 78
        label "{C66, C97}    {V23, V0, V44, V13, V43, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 79
        label "{C4, C97}    {V23, V52, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 80
        label "{C4, C100}    {V52, V0, V26, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 81
        label "{C4, C99}    {V52, V25, V0, V13, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 82
        label "{C67, C94}    {V23, V0, V13, V43, V19, V99, V89, V92}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      node [
        id 83
        label "{C18}    {V46, V39}"
        vgj [
          labelPosition "in"
          shape "Rectangle"
        ]
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 2
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 3
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 4
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 5
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 6
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 7
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 8
      ]

      edge [
        source 8
        target 9
      ]

      edge [
        source 8
        target 10
      ]

      edge [
        source 8
        target 11
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 12
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 13
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 14
      ]

      edge [
        source 14
        target 15
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 16
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 17
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 18
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 19
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 20
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 21
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 22
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 23
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 24
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 25
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 26
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 27
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 28
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 29
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 30
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 31
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 32
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 33
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 34
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 35
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 36
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 37
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 38
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 39
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 40
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 41
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 42
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 43
      ]

      edge [
        source 43
        target 44
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 45
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 46
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 47
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 48
      ]

      edge [
        source 48
        target 49
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 50
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 51
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 52
      ]

      edge [
        source 52
        target 53
      ]

      edge [
        source 53
        target 54
      ]

      edge [
        source 54
        target 55
      ]

      edge [
        source 52
        target 56
      ]

      edge [
        source 56
        target 57
      ]

      edge [
        source 56
        target 58
      ]

      edge [
        source 56
        target 59
      ]

      edge [
        source 59
        target 60
      ]

      edge [
        source 60
        target 61
      ]

      edge [
        source 61
        target 62
      ]

      edge [
        source 62
        target 63
      ]

      edge [
        source 63
        target 64
      ]

      edge [
        source 63
        target 65
      ]

      edge [
        source 65
        target 66
      ]

      edge [
        source 66
        target 67
      ]

      edge [
        source 52
        target 68
      ]

      edge [
        source 68
        target 69
      ]

      edge [
        source 52
        target 70
      ]

      edge [
        source 70
        target 71
      ]

      edge [
        source 71
        target 72
      ]

      edge [
        source 72
        target 73
      ]

      edge [
        source 11
        target 74
      ]

      edge [
        source 74
        target 75
      ]

      edge [
        source 74
        target 76
      ]

      edge [
        source 76
        target 77
      ]

      edge [
        source 77
        target 78
      ]

      edge [
        source 78
        target 79
      ]

      edge [
        source 79
        target 80
      ]

      edge [
        source 79
        target 81
      ]

      edge [
        source 78
        target 82
      ]

      edge [
        source 1
        target 83
      ]

    ]
```

How to parse them to XSD File or JavaObject ?

i want to have all gml file content in memory, to use them.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think that blueprints don't can exporting xsd file

Comment: i think that i havn't understood your anwser, i want to do this with java programme only

Comment: i have posted in main question the gml file example

Comment: http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/gml.html is Graph Markup Language